# Activate other worksheet via ComboBox

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, worksheet

I am trying to create a simple registration system. For this I created a userform including one ComboBox and four TextBoxes. The choice in the ComboBox should select in which worksheet the data is saved. The bug code is:

```
 Set ws = Worksheets("sheet")
    sheet = ComboBox1.Value
    Worksheets("sheet").Select
```

My total VBA code is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sheet As String


Set ws = Worksheets("sheet")
sheet = ComboBox1.Value

Worksheets("sheet").Select



' Verify if First Name is available
If Trim(Me.TextBox1.Value) = "" Then
    Me.TextBox1.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Voornaam ontbreekt"
    Exit Sub
End If

' Verify if Last Name is available
If Trim(Me.TextBox2.Value) = "" Then
    Me.TextBox2.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Achternaam ontbreekt"
    Exit Sub
End If

' Verify if Klasse is available
If Trim(Me.ComboBox1.Value) = "" Then
    Me.ComboBox1.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Klasse ontbreekt"
    Exit Sub
End If

' Verify if Paard is available
If Trim(Me.TextBox4.Value) = "" Then
    Me.TextBox4.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Naam paard ontbreekt"
    Exit Sub
End If


'find first empty row in database
iRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

'copy the data to the database
ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.TextBox1.Text
ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.TextBox2.Text
ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.ComboBox1.Text
ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.TextBox4.Text
ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.TextBox5.Text

'clear the data in all textbox

Dim ctl
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
If TypeOf ctl Is MSForms.TextBox Then
    ctl.Text = ""
End If

Next ctl

End Sub



Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
With ComboBox1
.AddItem "0,80 m"
.AddItem "0,90 m"
.AddItem "1 m"
.AddItem "1,10 m"
.AddItem "1,20 m"
.AddItem "1,30 m"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Which problem are you encountering?

Comment: first you set the variale and then use it: 
sheet = ComboBox1.Value
Set ws = Worksheets("sheet")
Worksheets("sheet").Select

Comment: You're saying that `sheet` is a worksheet then trying to say it's equal to `ComboBox1.Value`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, perhaps the below is what you want:

```
sheet = ComboBox1.Value
Set ws = Worksheets(sheet)
ws.Select
```

The problem with the original code is that the variable `sheet` after having been assigned, is never used, to select a sheet, etc.